# loading and using config files in python without arbitrary strings

Tags: python, serialization, configuration

I have an application with a config `yaml` file that looks like this (in reality it's much bigger):

```
amount_of_allowed_users: 10
```

I load the file to a variable named `config` and when I need to access the info I do:

```
config['amount_of_allowed_users']
```

however this seems precarious to me as it an arbitrary string in my code. what are the best practices when handling config file data?

In `C#` you would use [Xml Serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/examples-of-xml-serialization#serializing-a-class-that-contains-a-field-returning-a-complex-object) to create the config files and then deserialize it, are there similar methods in python?

---

I could have a python file act as a config file however it seems much less flexible.

Comment: Use [TOML](https://github.com/toml-lang/toml). Parser is here: https://pypi.org/project/toml/

Comment: how does it resolves the arbitrary string problem?